# How can I insert in Python multiple rows of a Dictionary with a WHERE condition?

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, where-clause, sql-insert

I need a little help. My problem is that I don't understand how to connect a WHERE condition in SQLite with the insertion of multiple elements from a dictionary.

My goal is to compare the Location Column from the Dictionary with the Country column from the existing table.

But I can't find a solution how to approach this, to implement a WHERE condition.

my code:

```
def add_countries_to_table(self, countryList):
       self.cursor.execute('''
          INSERT OR IGNORE INTO country (Country)
          VALUES (:Location)''', countryList)
       self.db.saveChanges()
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Simple. You don't. An insert is an insert, there is no `WHERE` clause in it.
You can define your Country to be UNIQUE and use an [`'UPSERT'`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_upsert.html) (UPDATE or INSERT) to ignore already existing values in the dictionary.

So `INSERT INTO country (Country) VALUES(:Location) ON CONFLICT(X) DO NOTHING` would be something close to the command you're looking for.

Alternatively you can try using a Set instead of a Dictionary to prevent duplicate values beforehand and let your program/script deal with duplicates instead of the DB.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a playholder. I presume you tried that with (:Location). There are many possibilities for placeholder. Normally placeholder would be ? or %s.
I presume you want to work with the values of the dict.
If you want to insert multiple rows you need to use a tulpe.

```
def add_countries_to_table(self, countryList):
       ctry_tl = ()
       for row in countryList['Location']:
         ctry_tulpe = (row)
         ctry_tl.append(ctry_tuple)
       self.cursor.execute('''
          UPSERT INTO country 
          VALUES (?)''', ctry_tl)
       self.db.commit()
```